# How to turn sound on and off in unity using a button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio, toggle, using

```
    public AudioListener audiolistenerr;
    private int SoundSetting;
```

these are my variables

```
    private void Start()
{
    PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Sound", 1);

    if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Sound", 1) == 1)
    {
        audiolistenerr.enabled = true;
        SoundSetting = 1;
        
    }

    if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Sound", 1) == 0)
    {
        audiolistenerr.enabled = false;
        SoundSetting = 0;
        
    }
}
```

My start method , it just checks wether sound was on or off using playerprefs

```
    public void MuteOrUnmuteSOund()
{
    if (audiolistenerr)
    {
        audiolistenerr.enabled = false;
        SoundSetting = 0;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Sound", SoundSetting);
        Debug.Log("Sound on");
    }

    if (!audiolistenerr)
    {
        audiolistenerr.enabled = true;
        SoundSetting = 1;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Sound", SoundSetting);
        Debug.Log("Sound off");
    }
}
```

And this is the code that my button executes when clicked, the sound wont toggle , I really dont know why. How do you make the button toggle the AudioListener?

Comment: Please specify the question within the body of your question. I know the title is basically the question, but for the purpose of proper documentation and and readability, put it at the end of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove ,1 like this:

```
    if(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Sound") == 1)
    {
        audiolistenerr.enabled = true;
        SoundSetting = 1;
        
    }

    if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Sound") == 0)
    {
        audiolistenerr.enabled = false;
        SoundSetting = 0;
        
    }`
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use else if statement in the start and in your method otherwise you are changing the conditions and checking them again.

```
if (audiolistenerr.enabled)
{
    audiolistenerr.enabled = false;
    SoundSetting = 0;
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Sound", SoundSetting);
    Debug.Log("Sound on");
}
else
{
    audiolistenerr.enabled = true;
    SoundSetting = 1;
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Sound", SoundSetting);
    Debug.Log("Sound off");
}
```

Comment: Its not working, really weird. Got any other solutions? Thanks alot for trying to help